# C++ CLI connect to MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, command-line-interface, mysql-connect

```cpp
using namespace sql;
using namespace sql::mysql;
sql::Driver* driver;
sql::Connection* con;
sql::Statement* stmt;
sql::ResultSet* res;    

driver = get_driver_instance();
```

I am using a user-defined function to connect to a MySQL DB. I get an error at `get_driver_instance();`. The function is inside:

```
public ref class MyForm2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
```

> Error - Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK2020 unresolved token (0A0006ED) "extern "C" class sql::Driver * __cdecl     _get_driver_instance_by_name    (char const * const)" (?_get_driver_instance_by_name@@$$J0YAPEAVDriver@sql@@QEBD@Z)    CForm1  C:\Users\Admin\source\repos    \CForm1\CForm1\MyForm2.obj    1